# how to design a generator for list loop in python3

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I want to design a generator as `gen(num):`

the idea is to generator a sequence of number. such as if `num=3`, the sequence will be `(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1.....)`. if `num=4`,  the sequence will be `(1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,....)`

```
def gen(num)
```

And how to use this generator in a for loop?

such as

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = gen(10)
for item in a:
    a+next(b)
```

it is good to use `next(b)` or we have better solution?

Comment: is the sequence following a certain pattern? Also, what would be the max length of the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def gen(n):
    c, i = 1, -1
    while True:
        if c in (1, n):
            i *= -1
        yield c
        c += i

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = gen(3)
for va, vb in zip(a, b):
    print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(va, vb, va + vb))
```

Prints:

```
1   1   2
2   2   4
3   3   6
4   2   6
5   1   6
6   2   8
7   3   10
8   2   10
9   1   10
10  2   12
```

Update: Version of the generator with `itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle

gen = lambda n: cycle([*range(1, n+1)] + [*range(n-1, 1, -1)])
```